# Securing folder in IIS 7 without requiring a user domain ie. DOMAIN\username

Tags: windows, security, iis, authentication, dns

I have secured a folder on my website using Windows authentication. I created a user on the server and gave them access to the folder while removing anonymous access.  This works fine, however if the user logs in via Internet Explorer they must specify the domain (ie. DOMAIN\username).

Is there anyway to not require the domain and just the username?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I had it working earlier but I didn't realize it as the URL being displayed wasn't https even though it was redirecting to HTTPS (the folder contained pdf files).  I

On the folder in the IIS browser, setup a custom error page for 403.4 and create an HTML file on the root of your site (redirectSSL.htm) to direct that error to.

Add this script to the file:

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Redirecting...</title></head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function redirectHttpToHttps()
    {
    var httpURL= window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    var httpsURL= "https://" + httpURL;
    window.location = httpsURL;
    }
    redirectHttpToHttps();
    </script>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then disable windows authentication and enable basic authentication. Click "edit" in basic authentication and specify the default domain.

This should work!